# Accessing a snowflake db within Flask and Windows IIS

Tags: python, iis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, urllib3

I've an issue that I can't solve by myself, maybe some of you did have the same problem before.

I'm running a Flask-App on a Windows Server using Windows IIS.
The Flask-App itself is running without any issues, however the app has some functionalities which requires the connection to a Snowflake database.

And here comes the issue, I'm not able to connect to the snowflake database within Windows IIS.
I've tested to run the app with waitress-serve which worked very well.
I'd like to use Windows IIS however, because of it's functionality to use the Windows Authentication to read the REMOTE USER.

The only error I'm getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git-projects\test-project\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\git-projects\test-project\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\vendored\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python\Python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: just as an additional information:
Accessing any other page doesn't work within IIS aswell, which can be already understood from the error.

Comment: It almost looks like you're not able to resolve the Snowflake account URL. How does the connection code looks like?

Comment: How the connection string configured? Application use app pool identity to connect  database on IIS. Does the app pool have permission to your database?

Comment: I'm using sqlalchemy to connect to the snowflake db:
```app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}&role={role}' ```

As already mentioned, the connection itself works outside of IIS, but for some reason IIS is not allowing the connection.

Comment: ```snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXX.snowflakecomputing.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/v1/login-request?request_id=XXX&databaseName=XXX&schemaName=XXX&warehouse=XXX&roleName=XXX&request_guid=XXX (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000005ECD0EA4A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

This is the exact error that I get (the values are replaced by "XXX")

Comment: Your wishes won't come true, as Snowflake does not support Windows authentication. You have to stick to one of the supported authentication methods, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#connecting-to-snowflake

Comment: The issue isn't the windows authentication?
Windows Authentication is used to login in into the flask app, the authentication to snowflake is done by default credentials

Answer (score 0):

So to let everyone know,

apparently you need to have the address you are trying to contact inside your company domain.
After letting the snowflake instance added to the domain, I was able to connect to it.

Hope this helps.